# How to plus a number to a specific cell in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to +1 to a cell in pandas dataframe

```
staff['pax'][0]= staff['pax'][0]+1
```

staff is the dataframe name, pax is the column name while 0 is the row I want to +1.
However below is the error..

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  staff['pax'][j]= staff['pax'][j]+1
C:\Mentor_Engine\test.py:53: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

I think the code is trying to copy the cell instead of +1 to the value in the cell, anyone could advise on how should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html

```
df.at[0, 'pax'] = df['pax'][0]+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .loc function :

```
staff.loc[0,"pax"] += 1
```